# How do I generate .class file if I have external Jar dependencies? Javac does not work

Tags: java, manifest, javac, executable-jar, manifest.mf

Background: Running on an ec2 instance not eclipse.

I have a java program that has external Jar dependencies. I want to create an executable jar file for this java program (being able to package the external jar files into this jar file would be icing on the cake)

The problem is that for me to use the java cf or cmf command I need to have a .class file. But, when I try javac HKP.java it throws a bunch of errors saying "xyz does not exist or cannot recognize symbol" which I'm guessing is because it has no idea about the external jar dependencies.

I have tried doing javac -sourcepath /home/ec2-user/apps/HKP/lib/ HKP.java, but it throws the exact same errors as before.

**EDIT** I have tried javac -classpath file1.jar, file2.jar, file3.jar HKP.java -I have also tried this with ";" in between. both return errors saying -bash file2.jar command not found, so instead of continuing the argument, bash is recognizing the multiple jar files as commands.This is the initial problem I had that caused me to post here.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: And did you add the jars to the classpath?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a new jar file, that will contain your code as well as the external jar(s), right?

Comment: @chrylis Yes, the 4 jars are in the lib/ directory mentioned in my class path, I also tried adding them individually. Thank you!

Comment: @MaxZoom Yes, that is correct. My first priority is creating a new executable jar file, second priority trying to have it contain the external jars as well. Thank you!

Comment: Just putting them in a directory doesn't do anything. I recommend a dependency-management system as described below.

Comment: I have added the solution below.

Comment: @Joe Yes, I see that this is a duplicate. Tbh, I spent a good hour and a half going through SO threads on this topic, but really the key to this question is the way you attach jar files which is ".:" rather than ";"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile a java source file into a class, you need to provide all classes which are used in that code on the classpath of the compiler.

If the classes come from (already compiled) external JARs, you typically do that by specifying `javac -classpath` with a list of JAR files, separated by `:` (on Linux). But you should really think about using an IDE or at least a maven build file (Which has the benefit, it can even download those JARs for you).

Both (Eclipse IDE and [Maven build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)) can also generate a ueber-jar with the external classes in there for easy execution.

Comment: I used a pom file and maven to get those external jar files. It created a jar file for my java program as well. Except, I can't execute that jar file using java -jar command. I've modified my pom file according to instructions on Overflow, but have had no luck. That is why I am trying the manifest way. Thank you

Comment: I have tried adding the external jar files individually as well putting them in a folder and then specifying that in the class path. Both have not worked. Thank you for the time and help!

Comment: You should ask only one answer at a time. This answer is about how to compile Java. But I added a link on how to build it with Maven.

Comment: You need to specify them individually for `javac`. On Unix/Linux with a ; separator: `javac -classpath lib/file1.jar;lib/file2.jar`. But if you have a POM where those libs are added as dependencies of type "compile", then this all happens automatically.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for my next question. I will also try your rec. I was separating the jar files with "," instead of ";" before

Comment: I tried javac -classpath lib/file1.jar;lib/file2.jar, but it wouldn't recognize the jar files after the first one. I would get something like this:
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
-bash: kafka-clients-0.8.2-beta.jar: command not found
-bash: metrics-core-2.2.0.jar: command not found
-bash: slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar: command not found

Comment: I am sorry I was mixing things up, for Linux it is ":" not ";". You need to specify it without a blank. (and with the sources).

Answer (score -2):

try to Add the path in system variable and restart your computer.

Comment: Where is the system variable? Also this is running on a ec2 instance rather than eclipse on my computer. Thank you!

Comment: He means setting an environment variable (called CLASSPATH) instead of specifying it with -cp.

Comment: You do not need to restart your computer - just checked.

Comment: @MaxZoom not always work if you didn't !